# Firefox Addon not working [Firefox 11]

Tags: 11.10, firefox

I have installed [FX Chrome theme](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fxchrome/) from the firefox [addons](https://addons.mozilla.org/) website. To tweak it I also installed [FX Chrome Mods](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fxchromemods/). But when I click on `Preferences` to open the settings of the FX Chrome Mod addon but it doesn't work. How to fix this? Please help!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Firefox add-ons are not compatible with the later versions of Firefox (like 11).   This may be your issue.

[Check out here for some other compaibility issues with this theme](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fxchromemods/reviews/)

Comment: Do you have any workaround for this?

Comment: no, unfortunately it's just a fact. unless you back version Firefox